# Runnable won't wait for function to finish

Tags: java, android, function, runnable, postdelayed

I'm trying to run every minute a refresh for the UI.
I wrote this code where I have an handler and a runnable with postdelay. Inside my runnable I have a call for a function that is returning a `Map` object. But every time, my runnable continues to the next lines of code before getting back the `Map` object from the function.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

**My Code:**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Map<String, String> varList = refreshVars(firstname, lastname, id);

        String newlastdate = varList.get("newlastdate");
        String newcurrentdate = varList.get("newcurrentdate");

        /*UI changes related to "newlastdate" and "newcurrentdate"*/
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
}
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);
```

**Function:**

```
public Map<String, String> refreshExitVars(final String FN, final String LN, final String IDN){
    final Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<>();
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    String nlastdate = jsonResponse.getString("date");
                    String ncurrentdate = jsonResponse.getString("currentdate");

                    list.put("newlastdate", nlastdate);
                    list.put("newcurrentdate", ncurrentdate);
                } else {
                    int ErrorCode = jsonResponse.getInt("errorcode");
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Exit.this);
                    builder.setMessage("" + ErrorCode)
                           .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    this.finish();
                                }
                            })
                           .create()
                           .show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    RequestUIChanges requestUIChanges = new RequestUIChanges(FN, LN, IDN, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Exit.this);
    queue.add(requestUIChanges);

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Your get map method is Asynchronous, no function will ever wait for it to return the values. You should probably do some study on how Volley works.

Answer (score 0):

As @MohammedAtif pointed out, the request you make in your `refreshExitVars()` method is asynchronous. That's why you have that `responseListener`. The `onResponse()` method of that listener is called when the asynchronous request is completed.

So the easiest way would be to move your `/*UI changes related to "newlastdate" and "newcurrentdate"*/` into your `onResponse()` method instead of trying to return the data.